# Tagging guidelines for Neural Network questions

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm getting somewhat involved in the `keras` tag, so I'm editing posts as best as I can. I'm always tempted to reduce the number of tags, but I have no idea how I'm supposed to do that.

Keras is a machine-learning/artificial-intelligence/neural-network framework written in Python (can run either 2 or 3) and can use either a TensorFlow or Theano back-end. What tags should the average question use?

- Should the `tensorflow`/`theano` tag be omitted unless these back-ends are being explicitly used?
- Should the `python` tag be omitted, unless the problem deals specifically how to use the Python code?
- When should the `neural-networks`, `machine-learning` and/or `artificial-intelligence` tags be used?

This problem applies to all neural-network framework questions. What to do about semi-redundant tagging?

Comment: There's also [tag:deep-learning], which you might wish to add to the list. My opinion here is that these tags don't matter that much in SO, because if someone is looking for technology-agnostic questions about AI, neural nets or machine learning, they should be looking at other sites in SE ([Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), etc.). Questions that are on-topic would involve at least one particular AI technology such as TensorFlow.